# Yocto Boot2Qt Build for Colibri iMX6ULL no wifi interface

Tags: kernel, wifi, firmware, yocto

I have built the linux distro Boot2Qt from [source](https://code.qt.io/cgit/yocto/meta-boot2qt.git/) with the yocto tools for the board Colibri iMX6ULL which has the integrated wifi chip `Marvell W8997-M1216`.

I installed the whole linux firmware-stack and i think also the correct kernel modules for the wifi chip.

There is no mlan interface showing up.

What exactly creates the mlan interface? 
Is there something else i need to install?

**Edit:**
I also am thankful for general answers on what prerequisites a linux os needs to have functional wifi, and what software exactly creates a wireless interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the correct kernel modules and its working now. Here the complete process:

Add the following lines to your local.conf:

```
BB_DANGLINGAPPENDS_WARNONLY ?= "true"

MACHINE ?= "colibri-imx6ull"

DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " wifi packagegroup-base-wifi dhcp-client"  // add wifi tools like iw and a dhcp client
MACHINE_FEATURES_append = " wifi"                                    // add wifi at machine level
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " linux-firmware dhcp-client"                 // install all firmware (needed for wifi) and the dhcp client
```

Next start menuconfig to add kernel modules by entering the build directory: `BUILD_DIR/meta-boot2qt/build-colibri-imx6ull/`
And run the command

```
bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig
```

If you get errors of undefined sysmbols you are probably missing the ncurses library. Install it with `sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev`

From the menu that opened in a console tab go to `Networking support > Wireless`.
Check the following modules:
[image: menuconfig]

Next go back to the main menu and enter `Device Drivers > Network device support > Wireless LAN`
Select the marvell drivers:
[image: menuconfig]

Save the changes and run:

```
bitbake b2qt-embedded-qt5-image
```

Now the necessary firmware, drivers and tools should be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [marvell driver manual page](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/drivers/net/wireless/marvell/mwifiex/README),

> a) Copy `sd8787.bin` to `/lib/firmware/mrvl/` directory, create the directory if it doesn't exist.
>
> b) Install WLAN driver,

```
insmod mwifiex.ko
```

> c) Uninstall WLAN driver,

```
ifconfig mlanX down

rmmod mwifiex
```

Also, you should validate which modules are being loaded on boot,

```
# Check the kernel buffer
dmesg

# List kernel modules
lsmod

# List PCI devices
lspci
```